# I'm using JQuery to update a table rows values from a modal input, but I've encountered a small issue. Can anyone take a look and give some advice?

Tags: jquery, html

I've encountered an odd issue with my update/edit table function. The function seems to work fine for 1 row, but the minute I add more than 1 row I get the issue. The most recent rows values get copied into the modal, rather than the values of that row. Then updating that row updates the row and the first row. I'm pretty confused right now by this issue.

Can anyone shed some light into this matter? I'm sure it's a logic issue.

Rows are added from an "add to table" button which calls a function on click.

```js
function editRow()
{
    $("#myTable tbody").on('click', '#edit', function (x) {

        let row = x.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        let name = $('#Name').val();//row.cells[1].textContent;
        let surname = $('#Surname').val(); //row.cells[2].textContent;
        console.log(row);
        console.log("Original name: " + name);
        console.log("Original surname: " + surname);//same thing
        //set edit modal values
        let edit_modal_name = $('#edit_Name').val(name);
        let edit_modal_surname = $('#edit_Surname').val(surname);


        console.log("Edit modal name: " + edit_modal_name.val());
        console.log("Edit modal surname: " + edit_modal_surname.val());

        $('#edit_modal').modal('show');

        $('#save_btn_edit').click(function () {
            row.cells[1].textContent =  $('#edit_Name').val();
            row.cells[2].textContent =  $('#edit_Surname').val();
            console.log(row);
        })
    });
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <title>Homework 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add to Table</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table id="myTable" class="table table-dark myTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Image</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Surname</th>
            <th scope="col">Edit</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- Add modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Data to Table</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="Image_input" for="Image" class="col-form-label">Image:</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="Image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="name_input" for="Name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="surname_input" for="Surname" class="col-form-label">Surname:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Surname">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="save_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary " data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Delete modal -->
<div class="modal" id="delete_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Row</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete this row?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_row_btn" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Edit Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="title">Edit Row Data</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="edit_Image_input" for="Image" class="col-form-label">Image:</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="edit_Image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="edit_name_input" for="Name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="edit_surname_input" for="Surname" class="col-form-label">Surname:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_Surname">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="save_btn_edit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a [**minimal** complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (+ [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)) that shows the actual problem. Right now there's nothing that calls `editRow()` or that would trigger your "edit" handler.

Comment: Why do you add a click handler on `tbody` for `#edit` in `editRow()`? Why do you add a click handler for `#save_btn_edit` in the click handler for `#edit`?

Comment: Assumption because of the description and the code -> Ids have to be unique

Comment: I tried accessing the ID's of each td element but i got an undefined value